# How to display the results of nearbysearch in android using Google Places API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-places

I'm developing an android application in which I can get the user's current location and display certain places around that location. For my app, the places I'm looking for are hospitals so the search URL is :

```
String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=hospital|health"+
                "My_API_KEY_HERE";
```

The problem I'm facing is in displaying the places, I run the app on my phone and it works and shows my location but nothing else (I'm using different markers for each location).

I tried using the Text Search Requests and I get the same result.

This is the MainActivity class:

```
package com.location.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MyMapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    //instance variables for Marker icon drawable resources
    private int userIcon, foodIcon, drinkIcon, shopIcon, otherIcon;

    //the map
    private GoogleMap theMap;

    //location manager
    private LocationManager locMan;

    //user marker
    private Marker userMarker;

    //places of interest
    private Marker[] placeMarkers;
    //max
    private final int MAX_PLACES = 20;//most returned from google
    //marker options
    private MarkerOptions[] places;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

        //get drawable IDs
        userIcon = R.drawable.yellow_point;
        foodIcon = R.drawable.red_point;
        drinkIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
        shopIcon = R.drawable.green_point;
        otherIcon = R.drawable.purple_point;

        //find out if we already have it
        if(theMap==null){
            //get the map
            theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            //check in case map/ Google Play services not available
            if(theMap!=null){
                //ok - proceed
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                //create marker array
                placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
                //update location
                updatePlaces();
            }

        }
    }

    //location listener functions

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "location changed");
        updatePlaces();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider disabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider enabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "status changed");
    }

    /*
     * update the place markers
     */
    private void updatePlaces(){
        //get location manager
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get last location
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
        //create LatLng
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //remove any existing marker
        if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();
        //create and set marker properties
        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lastLatLng)
        .title("You are here")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
        .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
        //move to location
        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

        //build places query string
        String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=hospital|health"+
                "API_KEY";//ADD KEY

        //execute query
        new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);

        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
    }

    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
            //fetch places

            //build result as string
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    //try to fetch the data

                    //HTTP Get receives URL string
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    //execute GET with Client - return response
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    //check response status
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    //only carry on if response is OK
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        //get response entity
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        //get input stream setup
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        //create reader
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        //use buffered reader to process
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        //read a line at a time, append to string builder
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }
        //process data retrieved from doInBackground
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //parse place data returned from Google Places
            //remove existing markers
            if(placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                    if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                }
            }
            try {
                //parse JSON

                //create JSONObject, pass stinrg returned from doInBackground
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //get "results" array
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                //marker options for each place returned
                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for (int p=0; p<placesArray.length(); p++) {
                    //parse each place
                    //if any values are missing we won't show the marker
                    boolean missingValue=false;
                    LatLng placeLL=null;
                    String placeName="";
                    String vicinity="";
                    int currIcon = otherIcon;
                    try{
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue=false;
                        //get place at this index
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        //get location section
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location");
                        //read lat lng
                        placeLL = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")), 
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));  
                        //get types
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                        //loop through types
                        for(int t=0; t<types.length(); t++){
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType=types.get(t).toString();
                            //check for particular types - set icons
                            if(thisType.contains("hospital")){
                                currIcon = foodIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("health")){
                                currIcon = drinkIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("doctor")){
                                currIcon = shopIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //vicinity
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        //name
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                    }
                    catch(JSONException jse){
                        Log.v("PLACES", "missing value");
                        missingValue=true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //if values missing we don't display
                    if(missingValue)    places[p]=null;
                    else
                        places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(placeLL)
                    .title(placeName)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                    .snippet(vicinity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length; p++){
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if(places[p]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[p]=theMap.addMarker(places[p]);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(theMap!=null){
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(theMap!=null){
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }

}
```

The layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    map:cameraTilt="45"
    map:cameraZoom="14"

    />
```

And the Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.location.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
    android:name="com.location.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.location.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As for the markers, they are just 4 markers in the drawble folder. 
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162174/4409409

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't use the [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/)? It is considerably easier to work with than trying to use the web API.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Do you have a working example I can fallow?

Comment: @DanielNugent thanks I'm checking it.

Comment: @Hadh - other than the [documentation on the site I linked](https://developers.google.com/places/android/current-place)?

Answer (score 4):

I think its ok to use the Google Places API Web Service instead of the Android SDK, because the [PlaceFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceFilter.html) from Android SDK can only filter by `openNow` and `placeID`. The advantage of Web Service is that it can also filter the results by `radius`, `minPrice` and `maxPrice` etc.

There are several issues in your code.

First your request URL missed the `&key=`, so it should be

```
String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=hospital|health"+
                "&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
```

Second you should use `HTTPURLConnection` class instead of the old `HttpGet` class, so you should revise your `doInBackground` method like below:

```
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
            //fetch places
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
                try {

                    URL requestUrl = new URL(placeSearchURL);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)requestUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.connect();
                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                        if (inputStream == null) {
                            return "";
                        }
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                            placesBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                        if (placesBuilder.length() == 0) {
                            return "";
                        }

                        Log.d("test", placesBuilder.toString());
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.i("test", "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.e("test", "Error processing Places API URL", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("test", "Error connecting to Places API", e);
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }
```

Third, you put the `locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);` inside your `updatePlaces()` method, you should remove it, because it will keep looping the `updatePlaces()` method, bad for your app and API quota limit. Also remove the `updatePlaces()` method inside your `onCreate()` method, and put these two line instead:

```
locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
```

So your updated `onCreate()` and `updatePlaces()` should be like this:

onCreate():

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);

        //get drawable IDs
        userIcon = R.drawable.yellow_point;
        foodIcon = R.drawable.red_point;
        drinkIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
        shopIcon = R.drawable.green_point;
        otherIcon = R.drawable.purple_point;

        //find out if we already have it
        if(theMap==null){
            //get the map
            theMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            //check in case map/ Google Play services not available
            if(theMap!=null){
                //ok - proceed
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                //create marker array
                placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
                //update location
                locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
            }
        }
    }
```

updatePlaces():

```
 private void updatePlaces(){
        //get location manager
        //get last location
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
        //create LatLng
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //remove any existing marker
        if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();
        //create and set marker properties
        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lastLatLng)
                .title("You are here")
                .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
        //move to location
        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

        //build places query string
        String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=hospital|health"+
                "&key=YOUR_API_KEY";//ADD KEY

        //execute query
        new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);
    }
```

You can also see the [updated code snippet](https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/72e28e0fb4b682ba9ab3). (I extends the `FragmentActivity` here, because I use the `SupportMapFragment` instead)

You can also view the image with markers here. (I dont have your marker images, so i just use the default marker image here)

[image]

Comment: @hadh are you able to resolve your issue yet? or does my answer help you? Thanks.