# customized Location on Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I m trying to get my Customized location on map. I am able to get my current location on map. I am not able to figure the starting point in displaying the customized location. Any help will be appreciated. 
(By customized locations, I mean for example like the list of restaurants which will be registered with my app)

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: Can you show your code of how you are storing the restaurant locations?

Comment: haven't got any leads on this. I am not able to find anything relevant that can give me an idea from where to start.

Comment: In that case I think this is too broad.  If you haven't started anything yet, you could use the Google Places Web API to get restaurants and display them on the map, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d/30162174#30162174

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have latitudes and longitudes of all the locations that you want to display on your map, you can use the following guide:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

If you don't have specific latitudes and longitudes but know the address you can retrieve latitudes and longitudes using the following:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

And yes, you can also use the Google Places API for a certain set of particular or specific places as mentioned in one of the comments: 
https://developers.google.com/places/android/start