# Google Place Api, How to find nearby places with range on Distance Radius for some specific place type?

Tags: android, google-places-api, distance

I am new to Google places api? I am making an android application in which I have to find all nearby places of some specific type for-example 'Park' within a specific distance radius lets say =20 km (i.e from user's current location) specified by User.

How can I do this using google api? Any help will be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to use the Google Places API for Android, or the Google Places web service API that returns JSON results?

Comment: Google Places API for Android

Comment: @DanielNugent If you can hep me for any case i'll be obliged

Comment: For using the web service api, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d/30162174#30162174

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try it

Comment: @DanielNugent i'm getting this error kindly help me.... This is the jason object returned to parser task

Comment: @DanielNugent  {"error_message":"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 110.38.255.216, with empty referer","html_attributions":[],"results":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}

Comment: I figured it out thanks for your help

Comment: @DanielNugent how to get Places photo what jason object getting is place  icon is there any way to get photo too.

Comment: Not sure offhand, I'll have to look in to that when I have time.