# Police Station finder application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

I am new to android and i am trying to *build a police station finder* application near my current location. I have a little idea how to do it with **map fragments** but map fragments don't work anymore. So, what is the other way to do the same?

Comment: Take a look at this answer that uses the Google Places Web API: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162174/4409409](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162174/4409409)

Comment: *"but map fragments don't work anymore"* - Say what now?

Comment: Oh, in America we just fire a gun into the air and they find us :)

Answer (score 0):

here you can get places near by your location using [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1) and for use of Place Api see [this blog](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)

hope this will help you.