# GoogleMaps displaying "locals" on wrong position

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

i want to display the `CurrentPosition` of the mobile phone and display all `bar|cafe` nearby the position.

The `CurrentPosition` works.

But the displaying of the bars/cafes is wrong. It seems like they are showing up from the center of vienna and not from the position of my phone.

Would be really thankful if someone could find the problem

MapsActivity.java

```
package androfenix.currentpositionandplacesnearby;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    LatLng latLng;
    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Mit setMapType setzen wir das Aussehen der Karte auf "Hybrid"
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        //Unregister for location callbacks:
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

        StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod());
        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
        placesTask.execute(sbValue.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }

    public StringBuilder sbMethod() throws SecurityException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=50000");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&keyword=" + "bar|cafe");
        sb.append("&key= SERVER API KEY ");

        Log.d("Map", "url: " + sb.toString());

        return sb;
    }

    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParserTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
    {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            Place_JSON placeJson = new Place_JSON();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                places = placeJson.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

            Log.d("Map", "list size: " + list.size());
            // Clears all the existing markers;
            //mGoogleMap.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);


                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                Log.d("Map", "place: " + name);

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
            }
        }
    }
    public class Place_JSON {

        /**
         * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
         */
        public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

            JSONArray jPlaces = null;
            try {
                /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
                jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
             * where each json object represent a place
             */
            return getPlaces(jPlaces);
        }

        private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {
            int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> place = null;

            /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
            for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
                try {
                    /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                    place = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
                    placesList.add(place);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return placesList;
        }

        /**
         * Parsing the Place JSON object
         */
        private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace)
        {

            HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String placeName = "-NA-";
            String vicinity = "-NA-";
            String latitude = "";
            String longitude = "";
            String reference = "";

            try {
                // Extracting Place name, if available
                if (!jPlace.isNull("name")) {
                    placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
                }

                // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
                if (!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")) {
                    vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
                }

                latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
                reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

                place.put("place_name", placeName);
                place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
                place.put("lat", latitude);
                place.put("lng", longitude);
                place.put("reference", reference);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return place;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the  [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/), you can discover the place where the device is currently located. That is, the place at the device's currently-reported location. Examples of places include local businesses, points of interest, and geographic locations.

If your app uses  [`PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceDetectionApi) must request the  [`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) permission.

The following code sample retrieves the list of places where the device is most likely to be located, and logs the name and likelihood for each place.

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
      Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
      placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
      placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
}
likelyPlaces.release();
}
});
```

The  [`PlacePicker`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker) provides a UI dialog that displays an interactive map and a list of nearby places, including places corresponding to geographical addresses and local businesses. Users can choose a place, and your app can then retrieve the details of the selected place.

The following code snippet retrieves the place that the user has selected:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
    String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
    Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```