# Using maps to find specific nearby places

Tags: android, google-maps

Good morning to everyone.
I'm trying to implement an activity to find some specific places nearby the user.

I tried this code: [MapActivity query for nearest hospital/restaurant not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971717/mapactivity-query-for-nearest-hospital-restaurant-not-working)

After some changes now the map is working and showing the user's current location, but not the places.

I have the API KEY and the Google Maps API activated. When I paste the url (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-15,287,-47.33&radius=5000000&types=restaurant&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCTZFZc7DBdk*) I receive the message:

> {
>      "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_",
>      "html_attributions" : [],
>      "results" : [],
>      "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
>   }

How can I fix it?

EDIT: my console is this way:
[image: APIS]
[image: API_KEY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got your api key mismatched

After seeing your screenshot...you should do couple of things:

1. First you should enable Google place api for Web service in Developer console..it is listed under `Google Maps APIs`

[image]

2. If u want to test your api from browser you should not put any restriction on the api key..select none in restriction..
3. Also test your nearby place api using this link: i think something is missing in your url

use this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&key=[your_api_key]

The following is a simple example of place nearby in Android. First, generate your query string for the API:

```
  public StringBuilder sbMethod() {

    //use your current location here
    double mLatitude = 37.77657;
    double mLongitude = -122.417506;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
    sb.append("&radius=5000");
    sb.append("&types=" + "restaurant");
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=******* YOUR API KEY****************");

    Log.d("Map", "api: " + sb.toString());

    return sb;
}
```

Here is the `AsyncTask` used to query the Places API:

```
 private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParserTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

Here is the `downloadURL`() method:

```
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
```

`ParserTask` for parsing the JSON result:

```
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        Place_JSON placeJson = new Place_JSON();

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            places = placeJson.parse(jObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

        Log.d("Map", "list size: " + list.size());
        // Clears all the existing markers;
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);


            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            Log.d("Map", "place: " + name);

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    }
}
```

Finally use the method as..

```
StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod());
PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
placesTask.execute(sbValue.toString());
```

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got the same message at the console and the app still shows only the current location from the user.

Comment: at the browser*

Comment: One doubt, @rafsanahmad007, the SHA1 is from the keystore used to export the apk or from the debug.keystore?

Comment: if u want to relese your app then you can use: SHA1 is from the keystore used to export the apk...but if it is in developing phase u should use debug sha1...from ur android studio

Comment: if it works..don't forget to accept and upvote the answer..thnkx