# Application does not Show nearby places to me

Tags: android

I want to display near by places to me by providing google API, i enabled Google Map Android API, Google places API for Android and Google places API web services also. but when i check the Provided URL on browser then it display the correct result on Browser but on Application did not display Near places to me, i did not what is wrong with me please any help me.

i followed this link [[MapActivity query for nearest hospital/restaurant not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971717/mapactivity-query-for-nearest-hospital-restaurant-not-working])

and this is my URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.669320,73.000433&radius=5000&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCrvLwbhrpHuo1V7OCz_tbYhogfIY10xaE

Comment: Post the code too

Comment: Sir my code in the Mention link , i updated my question

Comment: @Redman please help me

Comment: just read all the comments there and [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96501/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-bholagabbar)

Comment: @Redman i did'nt get any proper solution from the mention Chat if you help me please

Comment: @Daniel please help me

Comment: see [this](http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is correct but you need reduce radius 5000 to 50.

URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.669320,73.000433&radius=50&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCrvLwbhrpHuo1V7OCz_tbYhogfIY10xaE