# Google Places API Android find places via LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api, google-places, google-location-services

I am trying to use the Google Places API on Android to find Universities on a map based on where you click.

So ideally I could feed the Places API a coordinate and it could tell me the Universities around this coordinate. The PlaceDetectionAPI only has .getCurrentPlace and I don't just want where the user is currently.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like the Google Places Webservice API would do what you need, you can make a request for Universities around a radius at any lat/lon, and get the response in JSON format.  See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161395/im-trying-to-search-nearby-places-such-as-banks-restaurants-atms-inside-the-d/30162174#30162174

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) with "University" as a starting string to obtain nearby places that match that query.

Although that's not really the best solution, so you may want to get your own database of university coordinates and match them to your user's location.